# CakePHP SET error => false FOR All Forms

Tags: forms, cakephp

I want to handle application feedback regarding, in this case, form validation.
To do this I check for model validation in controller, using

```
// VALIDATE
            if ($this->Event->validates($this->data)) 
            {
                // SAVE
                    $this->Event->create();
                    if ($this->Event->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => false))) 
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Evenimentul a fost salvat!', 'flash_admin_success');
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Evenimentul nu a putut fi salvat. Va rugam sa incercati din nou!', 'flash_admin_error');
                    }
                ////////
                $errors = 'O EROARE';
                $this->set(compact('errors'));
            } 
            else 
            {
                // GET ERRORS to display it nicely :)
                    $errors = $this->Event->invalidFields();
                    $flash = '';
                    foreach($errors as $error)
                    {
                        $flash .= $error."<br />";
                    }
                    $this->Session->setFlash($flash, 'flash_admin_error');

            }
```

I know that there is a way to get rid of form field errors using 'error' => false, but i want to set this for the entire application, thus for all fields in all forms.
It has to be there a way of setting that fot the object itself, and I would be gratefull if someone would tell me.
Thaks a lot!

Comment: why so complicated? you seem to create a lot of overhead here for sth cake already covers out of the box...

Comment: I just want to customize validation error printig - to be more clear, I want to implement a jQueryUI at some point, so those errors would be placed into a "fancy" box. The code above is not final. Thx for your implide advice. I am shure that there are a lot of cases where i do as you say. With the time, I hope to become more efficient. If you know how to do what i asked in the first place, I do thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This doesn't really disable error output, but will hide the error: go to webroot/css/cake.generic.css add `display:none` to selector `div.error-message`. That's the simplest way to achieve what you want that I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just tried to set _inputDefaults like you suggested, but it had no effect even if i didn't overwrite it in the view form. If it worked for you, maybe i did something wrong, although I doubt that. If you can think of another way to do that, I am thankful!

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that finally I would have had to do that. Thanks a lot for the support!!

Answer (score 0):

Though it may seem like a bit of an extreme approach to override a single property, you can achieve this by extend the core FormHelper. This will allow you to make Anh Pham's [original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7376355/1) the default for all FormHelper instances:

```
// app/views/helpers/app_form.php
App::import('Helper', 'Time');
class AppFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    public $_inputDefaults = array('error' => false);

}
```

Now to use this as-is in CakePHP 1.3, you would have to use "`AppForm`" throughout your application to refer to this helper from now on (ie. `$this->AppForm->input()`). CakePHP 2.0 introduces helper aliasing to overcome this, but for now one has to resort to a bit of trickery to continue using "`Form`" instead. One blog post I found shows how to [backport the functionality](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/04/11/cakephp-back-port-helper-aliasing-to-cakephp-1-2-and-1-3/) and another manages allow the [helper to do it](http://reuben-in-rl.blogspot.com/2011/05/overriding-helpers-in-cakephp-13.html) itself. I personally use the following without any problems:

```
// app/views/app.php
class AppView extends View {

    function &_loadHelpers(&$loaded, $helpers, $parent = null) {
        $return = parent::_loadHelpers($loaded, $helpers, $parent);
        # rename App helpers (ie. AppHtml -> Html)
        foreach ($return as $helperName => $helper) {
            if (substr($helperName, 0, 3) === 'App') {
                $newHelperName = substr($helperName, 3);
                $return[$newHelperName] = $return[$helperName];
            }
        }
        # done
        return $return;
    }

}
```

To use the new created classes above, just add the following to your `AppController`:

```
// app/app_controller.php
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array(/*...*/, 'AppForm');

    public $view = array('App');

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Deizel! This is even more than I needed, but really wellcome information! Again, thx for your time!